Does a generalization of the Sokhotski-Plemelj Formula to four (or higher) dimensions exist?
The Sokhotski-Plemelj Formula states
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{x \pm \textbf i \eta} = \mathcal{P} \left(\frac1x\right) \mp \textbf i\pi \delta(x)
\end{equation}
where this expression has to be understood inside of an integral, $\mathcal{P}$ is the principal value, and $\eta\rightarrow 0$.
An extension of this does exist for two dimensions, namely the Poincaré-Bertrand formula with
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{x_1 - \textbf i s_1\eta} \frac{1}{x_2 - \textbf i s_2 \eta} = \left(\mathcal{P} \left(\frac1{x_1}\right) + \textbf i\pi s_1\delta(x_1)\right) \left(\mathcal{P} \left(\frac1{x_2}\right) + \textbf i\pi s_2\delta(x_2)\right) + \pi^2 \delta(x_1)\delta(x_2)
\end{equation}
where $s_j = \pm 1$.
My question is if there exists an extension to four (or possibly higher) dimensions to evaluate integrals that contains expressions like
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{x_1-\textbf i s_1 \eta} \frac{1}{x_2- \textbf i s_2\eta} \frac{1}{x_3-\textbf i s_3 \eta} \frac{1}{x_4-\textbf i s_4 \eta} =?
\end{equation}

Do you know how to arrive at the expressions you wrote?

For the Sokhotski-Plemelj Formula you can integrate along the upper complex-plane with a semi-circle that excludes the pole. The integral along the outer circle tends to zero for functions with $f(R\rightarrow \infty)\rightarrow c$. The integrals along the axis simplify to the principle value  and the small circle at the pole yields the delta function. For the Poincaré-Bertrand formula, you can use partial fractions and then employ the  Sokhotski-Plemelj Formula. I tried doing this for the four-dimensional case but without success.

Are you sure that you have written the first product correctly? I don't understand why it's not just
$$
\frac{1}{x_1 - \textbf i s_1\eta} \frac{1}{x_2 - \textbf i s_2 \eta} = \left(\mathcal{P} \left(\frac1{x_1}\right) + \textbf i\pi s_1\delta(x_1)\right) \left(\mathcal{P} \left(\frac1{x_2}\right) + \textbf i\pi s_2\delta(x_2)\right).$$
